# Nswag.Msbuild failed after switching to x86

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, x86, swagger, nswag

I have an asp.net core 3.0 project and I use NSwag.AspNetCore / NSwag.MsBuild (13.1.6).
I need to run my project in 32 bits, but after I changed my configurations to compile in x86 instead of x64 nswag generation started to fail and I can't find any help in the documentation about runing nswag in 32 bits.

I get this error during the build :

```
4>NSwag command line tool for .NET Core NetCore30, toolchain v13.1.6.0 (NJsonSchema v10.0.28.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))
4>Visit http://NSwag.org for more information.
4>NSwag bin directory: C:\Users\William\.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.1.6\tools\NetCore30
4>
4>Executing file 'nswag.json' with variables 'Configuration=Debug'...
4>Launcher directory: C:\Users\William\.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.1.6\tools\NetCore30
4>System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
4> ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly '#########.WebUI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Tentative de chargement d'un programme de format incorrect.
4>File name: '########.WebUI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
4>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, RuntimeAssembly assemblyContext, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
4>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
4>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
4>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
4>   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToOpenApiGeneratorCommandEntryPoint.GetServiceProvider(String applicationName) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Generation\AspNetCore\AspNetCoreToOpenApiGeneratorCommandEntryPoint.cs:line 42
4>   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToOpenApiGeneratorCommandEntryPoint.Process(String commandContent, String outputFile, String applicationName) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Generation\AspNetCore\AspNetCoreToOpenApiGeneratorCommandEntryPoint.cs:line 26
4>
```

Here is the task in my .csproj :

```
  <Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Reference)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)References" />
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Core30) run /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutDir)References" />
  </Target>
```

The nswag.json :

```
{
  "runtime": "NetCore30",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "aspNetCoreToOpenApi": {
      "project": "WebUI.csproj",
      "msBuildProjectExtensionsPath": null,
      "configuration": null,
      "runtime": null,
      "targetFramework": null,
      "noBuild": true,
      "verbose": false,
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "requireParametersWithoutDefault": true,
      "apiGroupNames": null,
      "defaultPropertyNameHandling": "CamelCase",
      "defaultReferenceTypeNullHandling": "Null",
      "defaultDictionaryValueReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
      "defaultResponseReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
      "defaultEnumHandling": "Integer",
      "flattenInheritanceHierarchy": false,
      "generateKnownTypes": true,
      "generateEnumMappingDescription": false,
      "generateXmlObjects": false,
      "generateAbstractProperties": false,
      "generateAbstractSchemas": true,
      "ignoreObsoleteProperties": false,
      "allowReferencesWithProperties": false,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceBasePath": null,
      "serviceSchemes": [],
      "infoTitle": "####### API",
      "infoDescription": null,
      "infoVersion": "1.0.0",
      "documentTemplate": null,
      "documentProcessorTypes": [],
      "operationProcessorTypes": [],
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "schemaNameGeneratorType": null,
      "contractResolverType": null,
      "serializerSettingsType": null,
      "useDocumentProvider": true,
      "documentName": "v1",
      "aspNetCoreEnvironment": null,
      "createWebHostBuilderMethod": null,
      "startupType": null,
      "allowNullableBodyParameters": true,
      "output": "wwwroot/api/specification.json",
      "outputType": "OpenApi3",
      "assemblyPaths": [],
      "assemblyConfig": null,
      "referencePaths": [],
      "useNuGetCache": false
    }
  },
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToTypeScriptClient": {
      "className": "{controller}Client",
      "moduleName": "",
      "namespace": "",
      "typeScriptVersion": 2.7,
      "template": "Angular",
      "promiseType": "Promise",
      "httpClass": "HttpClient",
      "useSingletonProvider": true,
      "injectionTokenType": "InjectionToken",
      "rxJsVersion": 6.0,
      "dateTimeType": "Date",
      "nullValue": "Undefined",
      "generateClientClasses": true,
      "generateClientInterfaces": true,
      "generateOptionalParameters": false,
      "exportTypes": true,
      "wrapDtoExceptions": false,
      "exceptionClass": "SwaggerException",
      "clientBaseClass": null,
      "wrapResponses": false,
      "wrapResponseMethods": [],
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
      "protectedMethods": [],
      "configurationClass": null,
      "useTransformOptionsMethod": false,
      "useTransformResultMethod": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromOperationId",
      "markOptionalProperties": true,
      "generateCloneMethod": false,
      "typeStyle": "Class",
      "classTypes": [],
      "extendedClasses": [],
      "extensionCode": null,
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "excludedParameterNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateConstructorInterface": true,
      "convertConstructorInterfaceData": false,
      "importRequiredTypes": true,
      "useGetBaseUrlMethod": false,
      "baseUrlTokenName": "API_BASE_URL",
      "queryNullValue": "",
      "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
      "inlineNamedAny": false,
      "templateDirectory": null,
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "propertyNameGeneratorType": null,
      "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceSchemes": null,
      "output": "ClientApp/src/app/########-api.ts"
    }
  }
}
```